# JavaScript / JQuery - Meios de remover o conteúdo de uma <TD>

Tags: javascript, html5

Como eu posso remover o conteúdo de uma `td`, por exemplo este código:

```html
<table id="tblItens" width="400px">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button> teste </button>
```

Qual o meio em js que posso usar para remover os elementos da TD?

Comment: Você quer remover o conteúdo da <td> a partir da iteração de um botão, um click? teria como explicar melhor , ou a que se aplica o exemplo?

Comment: Sim, através de um onclick do button

Comment: São 3 tds. De qual td vc quer remover?

Comment: Gostaria de saber quais são os modos de remover o conteúdo, tanto de uma td e de todas

Comment: @Sora Por favor, seja um pouco mais específico. Você precisa remover uma `td` dentro de uma `tr`, certo? Mas qual o critério pra isto? Ou você apenas quer saber qual função podes usar para removê-la?

Comment: Gostaria de saber somente qual função pode remover tanto um elemento quanto todos os elementos das `tds` dentro desta table @LINQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para remover individualmente basta atribuir um trigger a cada `td`, e pega-las com o `this`.

```js
let td = document.querySelectorAll('td');

for(item in td)
  td[item].onclick = function(){ this.parentNode.removeChild(this); }
```

```html
<table id="tblItens" width="400px">
     <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
<span>Clique na td para remove-la<span>
```

Para remover todas basta percorrer todas e remove-las ao clicar no botão.

```js
let td = document.querySelectorAll('td');
let apagar = document.querySelector('#apagar');

apagar.onclick = function(){
  for(item in td) 
  if(td[item].parentNode) td[item].parentNode.removeChild(td[item]);
}
```

```html
<table id="tblItens" width="400px">
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<button id="apagar"> apagar </button>
```

Comment: Perfeito, vou estudar o código para entender direito como proceder

Comment: Obrigado @Felipe

Comment: Denada @Sora, no segundo código estava dando um erro no console caso o parentNode não existisse, mas já arrumei e editei  :)

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi você apenas quer saber como excluir um elemento qualquer do DOM.

Bem, sendo `elemento` o elemento que você quer remover, é possível fazer o seguinte

```
elemento.parentNode.removeChild(elemento);
```

Veja um exemplo:

```js
document.getElementById('bt').addEventListener('click', function() {
  const id = document.getElementById('txtrem').value;
  const el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
});
```

```html
<table id="tblItens" width="400px">
  <tr>
    <td id="td1">1</td>
    <td id="td1">2</td>
    <td id="td1">3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<label>Digite o Id que deseja remover</label><br>
<input type="text" id="txtrem">
<button id="bt"> teste </button>
```

Comment: Perfeito, para remover todos os elementos é necessário um for certo?

Comment: @Sora Aí é melhor fazer `innerHtml = ''`. Isso vai limpar todo o conteúdo dentro de um elemento.

Comment: Ah sim, obrigado pela ajuda @LINQ

Answer (score 1):

Para remover os elementos filhos das `<td>`s, utilize o método [`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) no jQuery, ou com javascript puro bastaria algo como `elementoTd.innerHTML = '';`.

Answer (score 1):

Remover o conteúdo de todas as `tds`:

```js
botao = document.querySelector("button");
botao.addEventListener("click", function(){
   var tabela = document.querySelector("#tblItens");
   var TDs = tabela.getElementsByTagName("td");
   for(idx in TDs){
      TDs[idx].innerHTML = '';
   }
});
```

```html
<table id="tblItens" width="400px">
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<button> Remover tudo </button>
```

Remover pelo conteúdo de uma `td`:

```js
botao = document.querySelector("button");
botao.addEventListener("click", function(){
   var conteudo = "2"; // exemplo, td que tiver "2"
   var tabela = document.querySelector("#tblItens");
   var TDs = tabela.getElementsByTagName("td");
   for(idx in TDs){
      if(TDs[idx].innerHTML == conteudo){
         TDs[idx].innerHTML = "";
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<table id="tblItens" width="400px">
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<button> Remover pelo conteúdo </button>
```

Comment: Perfeito !! Vou estudar este modelo pois creio que será o que precisarei usar futuramente, obrigado @DvD